How to know if the HttpServletRequest getParameter() method result is coming from a query parameter,x-www-form-url-encoded or multipart/form-data?
I'm working on a plain java project and I'm using Tomcat 10 as a dependency.
What options do I have in java servlets to know if the getParameter() method result is coming from a query parameter,x-www-form-url-encoded or multipart/form-data ?
@MultipartConfig()
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
     
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest  request,HttpServletResponse response){
            
            String param = request.getParameter("username");
            response.setContentType("text/plain"); 
            PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
            pw.println(param);       
            pw.close(); 
    }
}

